# auto scrolling to bottom of page

Tags: php, anchor

I have a form on the bottom of my webpage, when i submit the form and the page refreshes i would like for the page to automatticly be positioned at the bottom of the page so i see the form again. Is it possible to achieve this without using any javascript, only with php.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. You can do this using the [name attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_links.asp) of a link.

At the bottom of your page have this code:

```
<!-- The page with the form (script.php) -->
<?php
  //Other page content
?>
<a name="bottomOFThePage"></a>
<?php
 //Your form
?>

<!--
    PHP page that handles the form submit
    Use the header code from netcoder's answer below
-->
<?php
  //Process your form
 header('Location: script.php#bottomOfPage');
?>
```

Redirect after you submit the form to http://yoururl.com/script.php#bottomOfThePage

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this without JavaScript is to put an anchor tag at the bottom of your page:

```
<a name="bottomOfPage"></a>
```

Then, redirect the user to the bottom of the page (or submit a form to):

```
<?php
header('Location: script.php#bottomOfPage');
exit;
```

Comment: `href`? You mean `name`, don't you?